# Can 太久 be used to refer to time past between two dates?

Tags: translation

As an example, if I am making plans to meet with a friend, and I say I am free on a specific date, say 2 weeks from now, and then I follow up by asking my friend "Or is that too far ahead?" To translate "Or is that too far ahead?" into Mandarin, can one say "会不会太久？“? Or is there a better translation?

Comment: You can. You can say 這會不會太久了?

Comment: 太久 can certainly be used to refer to time between two dates, but I'd use it mainly in the case of processes, for instance, one needs to wait for several days to get a visa, in which case one can complain, `要好几天才能拿到签证, 太久了`. In your case, I'd ask `2周以后会不会太晚了`?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty good.

Besides, I want to explain the difference between "太久" and "太迟".

"太久" means you spend long time. "太迟" means you spend long time and don't know whether something will what happen.

for example:

Your friend live the same city with you. You are going to visit him after two weeks.

you can say "我两个星期后来看你，会不会太久？";

Your friend has a trip in your city. You plan to meet him after two weeks. But you don't know when he will return home, you are afraid that he will have gone back home by the time you visit him.

You can say "我两个星期后来看你，会不会太迟？";

Answer (score 1):

"太久" really means the period between a time and another one, the distance is too far for us to wait for. You can translate it as, "It's a bit too late." Because when you hear this statement, usually means someone is not much patient to wait for others, maybe come with some complaining.

Comment: "It't a bit too late." should be translated as "有點太晚", I think its meaning is different from "太久".

Comment: Yes, but sometimes when we hear：你怎么才来？我等的太久了。Here "太久" obviously means "晚".

Comment: I think you should say "你怎麽现在才来？你让我等太久了", "你怎么才来？我等的太久了" doesn't sound right, I never hear people say it in that way(I am a Taiwanese), 太久 I think is mostly used to describe the waiting process is too long, while 晚 means late, the meaning of two is of course different.

Comment: In the mainland of China we usually say something like this, maybe the difference cultures;)

Comment: I wouldn't say 我等的太久了 either, but 我等了好久...

Answer (score 1):

You can ask 会不会太早约定? (Is it too early to make such an appointment?)

Answer (score -1):

For "is that too far ahead", it should be “太旧**之后**”,
For "too long (PERIOD)", it should be ‘太久’.

Comment: 太旧,does 太旧 means too old? You seem picked up the wrong character.

Comment: Which old are you meaning? The people's ages?（太老） The history / historical items?

Comment: I mean items. When you say something is 太旧\舊, you mean it's too old.